# Custom ROM and 4g/ LTE error.

Tags: samsung, settings, custom-roms, internet, mobile-network

I installed Noble ROM in my SM J200G. After installing it, I was not unable to connect to LTE which I was before. My stock rom, when rooted, used to connect to LTE without any error. My carrier is Airtel (India). What should I do to connect to LTE? I have correct internet pack which allows 4g/3g.

In my phone settings, the data mode it LTE/WCDMA auto mode.

Comment: Sounds like a ROM issue, would recommend returning back to stock.

Comment: Revert back the stock, Luke! That's it.

Comment: dont revert back there is an option
go to youtube and search for this yo will find volte fix file just go to system and paste all files their